# Creating partially rounded meshes

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-view, subdivision-surface, blend-files

In the image, I want to create the axis parts (red circle):

[image]

I tried creating separate meshes with no modifiers (Cube.001 and Cube.003 (attached blend file)) but I wanted to make the top rounded by adding modifiers, but when applying the subsurf modifier to a disjointed mesh (more "isles" of connected vertexes the modifier is applied in reference to the geometric origin of the whole mesh (and not each submesh ("isle")).

Questions:

- is it a good idea to have multiple separate meshes (either individual meshes of subsets of vertexes within a mesh) and place the close together so that it looks ok? and not create ngons
- related to first, is it ok to split the mesh up into individual meshes, apply modifiers on these and then remerge?

[image]

Comment: You don't say what's your final purpose, is it for images, animations, close-up shots or not, 3D printing, etc? In my opinion it's always better to try it as one object; if it's too hard, use boolean and then apply and correct the topology, etc... If you are in a hurry and it's just to give illusion, you can quicly make separate parts

Comment: Animations; I'm trying to create parts of the rims that would need to spin (and turn on other models). Is it ok to have multiple meshes with modifiers closed to each other that are merged into a single mesh but not topologically?

Comment: The important thing at the end is that you can't see that it's made of seperate parts when it is supposed to be one part. You can join them all (ctrl J) to make one object, or, if they all need to keep their own modifiers, you can parent them to the main object